# HOMO / LUMO energies in a qualitative view

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, orbitals

I have a question regarding the *HOMO* and *LUMO* energies depending on various effects like substituents and electronegativity. It seems to be a somewhat known topic but I cannot really find a clear 
answer anywhere that would just summarize those effects. So I started to wrap my head around various qualitative effects that you can attribute to either a large or a small *HOMO-LUMO* gap.

The easiest approach would therefore be considering *Koopman's* theorem, where the negative *HOMO* energy approximates the ionization potential and the negative *LUMO* energy approximates the electron affinity.
If we then move to *Mulliken's* definition of electronegativity we can see that the sum of both *IP* and *EA* (divided by two) serve as a good approximation to the electronegativity. Which means that upon many other effects the electronegativity
seems to be a key feature to describe the *HOMO* and *LUMO* energy. And this is also what I remember from lectures.

In my memory a more electronegative element will lower the energy of the *LUMO*. That is why in for example photocatalysis many conjugated heterocyclic (N-substituted) ligands are used. The lower π*-orbitals give rise to *MLCT* transitions.
On the other hand the *HOMO* energy should be increased as well.

If we move to the *Klopman-Salem* equation we can derive that according to *HSAB* concept a large *HOMO-LUMO* gap will be a pair of a hard acid and a hard base and a small *HOMO-LUMO* gap will be a soft-soft pair.
One simplification to this is the case of a Lewis-acid and a Lewis-base reacting, or an electrophile and a nucleophile. Here the *HOMO* of the nucleophile will interact with the *LUMO* of the electrophile.
This means that a high nucleophilicity requires a high *HOMO* energy. Unfortunately there is no good description besides lone-pairs on real nucleophilic strenght.

So I thought I could perhaps find other examples and therefore moved to carbenes and their analogues. We destinguish singulett and triplett carbenes. A singulett carbene has a larger *HOMO-LUMO* gap. 
Moving to heavier elements we get more singulett character. But this can't be used here since this effect is due to more complicated effects. As Si-Si-bonds and double bonds tend to be be much more reactive and are easily photo-activated as well the *HOMO-LUMO* gap should be smaller than in corresponding C-C-bonds.
But what about substituents on the carbene? Here we find that electronegative ligands will stabilize the a1-orbital in the carbene and in for example aminocarbenes, the π-donor-function of the $\ce{NH2}$-group increases the energy of the b1-orbital.

So from these examples I would summarize that in general the inductive effect of an electronegative substituent will stabilize and therefore descrease the energy of the *HOMO*. 
And a π-donor will increase the energy of the LUMO by destabilizing it.
Comparing this to ligand field theory I would conclude that having an alkyl group will destabilize and therefore increse the *HOMO* and a π-acceptor will descrease the energy of the *LUMO*.

Are my findings and ideas somewhat applicable and true? And are there other very simple effects that I can take into consideration if I want to describe the relative positions of the *HOMO* and *LUMO*?